# how to submit form using jsoup in https website

Tags: android, authentication, https

i try send values(https website) get cookies and redirect otherpage.aspx use this login cookies . But cookies do not work (this code working on http websites). I shared my code what is the wrong ?

In addition to i do basicly this process with HtmlUnit (java) library but Android not support this library. What is the best alternative (htmlunit) library  for android ?

Thank you in advance.

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://abc.com/index.aspx")

                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .data("textKulID", "USERNAMEISHERE")
                    .data("textSifre", "PASSISHERE")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();

             doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://abc.com/otherpage.aspx")
                     .followRedirects(true)
                     .cookies(res.cookies())
                        .post();
```